# How can I generate all the possible binary lists with 4 elements? (Using Python)

Tags: random, binary, sublist

I'm wondering is there a way I can generate a list whose sublists are all the possible combinations of 0 and 1 with 4 elements? To generate an individual sublist, I have

```
import random
binum = np.random.randint(2, size=4).tolist()
```

But how can I get a full list to contain all the possible sublists, each appears once? So the desired output looks like:

```
[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1]...[1,0,0,1]...[1,1,1,1]]
```

(There're 16 elements in total for this case). Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate over numbers from 0 to 15 and get their binary representation:

```
In [1]: N = 4    

In [2]: def getbit(value, bitnum):
   ...:     mask = 1 << bitnum
   ...:     return (value & mask) >> bitnum
   ...: 

In [3]: [[getbit(i, j) for j in range(N)] for i in range(2 ** N)]
Out[3]: 
[[0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Same in numpy:

```
np.unpackbits(np.expand_dims(np.arange(2 ** N, dtype=np.uint8), -1),
              axis=1, bitorder='little', count=N)
```

Also, you can generate the next element by implementing increment operation on binary array:

```
def gen(l=4):
    a = [0 for _ in range(l)]
    while True:
        yield a.copy()
        i = 0
        while i < l and a[i]:
            a[i] = 0
            i += 1
        if i == l:
            break
        a[i] = 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much:)

Answer (score 3):

You basically want all the binary numbers from 0 to 2**n. So, you could use the following code to generate them:

```
def get_binary_numbers(n):
    format_str = f"0{n}b"
    max_binary_number = 2**n
    return [list(format(i, format_str)) for i in range(max_binary_number)]
```

Be careful with its performance, if you need big values of n then maybe use the same idea with other ways to generate the lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the cartesian product of your input using itertools library

```
from itertools import product

bit_sets = product(range(2), repeat=4)
# format your data code ...
```

more details at https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html?highlight=combinations#itertools.product

Answer (score 0):

This just needs the actual necessary parameters from @yesk13's answer, really, using the cartesian product from itertools

```
for p in it.product([0, 1], repeat=4):
    print(p)

(0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 1, 0)
(0, 0, 1, 1)
(0, 1, 0, 0)
(0, 1, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 1, 0)
(0, 1, 1, 1)
(1, 0, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 0, 1)
(1, 0, 1, 0)
(1, 0, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 0, 0)
(1, 1, 0, 1)
(1, 1, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 1, 1)
```